# Why is the normalization constant for the covariance std(x)std(y)?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I understand that the correlation coefficient is just the normalized covariance, where covariance is

$\mathrm{cov}(x, y) \equiv \mathrm{E}[(x-\bar{x})(y-\bar{y})]$

From the definition of the correlation coefficient, I know that the normalization constant is $\sigma_x\sigma_y$, or equivalently I suppose that the maximum value of the covariance is $\sigma_x\sigma_y$.

I have an intuitive understanding of why this should be the case (the root-square combination in the standard deviation gets rid of all the negative signs) but is there a more rigorous way of proving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to invoke Cauchy-Schwartz inequality:

$\mathrm{cov}(x, y) \equiv \mathrm{E}[(x-\bar{x})(y-\bar{y})] \leq \sqrt{\mathrm{E}[(x-\bar{x})^2]}\sqrt{\mathrm{E}[(y-\bar{y})^2]}$

And the left hand side quantities are the standard deviations you are looking for.